Is this a valid instance of strengthening the antecedent?

There exists no greatest natural number
Proposition 1 is true
In FOL, Proposition 1 can be translated as $\lnot\exists a\forall b\left(a,b\in N\land\left(a\neq b\rightarrow a>b\right)\right)$
$\lnot\exists a\forall b\left(a,b\in N\land\left(a\neq b\rightarrow a>b\right)\right)$ is equivalent to $\forall a\exists b\left(a,b\in N\rightarrow\left(a\neq b\land a\le b\right)\right)$, which is also true.
By strengthening the antecedent, Proposition 4 entails $\forall a\exists b\left(a,b\in N\land a,b\in P\rightarrow\left(a\neq b\land a\le b\right)\right)$
Since proposition 4 is true, then  $\forall a\exists b\left(a,b\in N\land a,b\in P\rightarrow\left(a\neq b\land a\le b\right)\right)$ is true too.
And since $\forall a\exists b\left(a,b\in N\land a,b\in P\rightarrow\left(a\neq b\land a\le b\right)\right)$ is true, then $\lnot\exists a\forall b\left(a,b\in N\land a,b\in P\land\left(a\neq b\rightarrow a>b\right)\right)$ is true.
Note, P stands for the set of prime numbers. N stands for the set of natural numbers

